# Подключение к SQL-базе данных через Lua-скрипт *(ODBC)

Tags: sql, sql-server, lua, odbc

Всем привет!
Есть простой скрипт на LUA, с помощью которого по инструкции:
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Lua+API+Reference#LuaAPIReference-freeswitch.Dbh
пытаюсь подключиться к существующей SQL-базе данных.

```
local dbh = freeswitch.Dbh("odbc://ИМЯ_БАЗЫ:ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ:ПАРОЛЬ") 
assert(dbh:connected())
```

ОС Windows Server 2019 Standart.
Запускаю данный скрипт через FreeSwitch командой:

```
luarun db_external_test.lua
```

Получаю сообщение о ошибке подключения:
[Microsoft][─ИРяЕЄўЕР ДРАЙВЕРОВ ODBC] ╚РЄОўНИъ ДАННЫї НЕ НАЙДЕН И НЕ єъАчАН ДРАЙВЕР, ИРяОы№чєЕьЫЙ яО єьОыўАНИ■
Перевод:
*[ERR] switch_odbc.c:368 STATE: IM002 CODE 0 ERROR: [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию')
[CRIT] switch_core_sqldb.c:508 Failure to connect to ODBC ИМЯ_БАЗЫ!
[ERR] freeswitch_lua.cpp:374 Connection failed.  DBH NOT Connected.*

Предположил, что не настроил ODBC на сервере.
Что сделал:

1. Установил Microsoft® ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server:
   https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=50420
2. Настроил "Источники данных ODBC (64-разрядная версия)" в разделе "Администрирование" на сервере.

[image: Что было настроено]

К сожалению, после всех этих манипуляция сообщение о ошибке при попытке запуска скрипта всё равно сохранилось, что ещё я не донастроил? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение в моём случае: при настройке "Источники данных ODBC (64-разрядная версия)" на самом первом шаге указал неверное имя сервера.
Нужно указывать имя того, к которому подключаешься.
Всем спасибо за ментальную поддержку )